# Which NTP server should I use?

Tags: ubuntu, ntp

I want to set up the `NTP server` in my servers that are located in Frankfurt, using UTC as timezone. But I don't know which NTP server should I use.

This is the result from the `ubuntu ntp server`:
[image: ubuntu]

And this is the result from `europe ntp server`:
[image: europe]

I know that the european NTP server is taking less time to give me a reply, right ? But the Ubuntu server is giving me a better `offset` and `jitter` result ?

Which one of these server should I use ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stratum (`st`): How close the server is to an actual reference time source

Offset (ms): The time your system clock is off the time server

Delay (ms): How long the response took to get here and back (`RTT`)

Jitter (ms): difference between 2 samples

Reach: Number of syncs

---

You should use the europe ntp servers because:

- You have a lower delay
- Lower average stratum
- Likely lower jitter (The above output for the ubuntu servers only did one sync, so no jitter)

You should **NOT** use the europe ntp servers because:

- You wish to run your own time server (at Stratum 3)
- You are syncing with other time servers (all your other servers in Europe) from your time server

---

**Instead** I would head over to `www.pool.ntp.org` and look at [their list of Stratum 2 time servers](http://support.ntp.org/bin/view/Servers/StratumTwoTimeServers) and configure a few of these manually. What to look for in the manual selection is to choose a server that is physically close and has a very low delay. There is a list of Stratum 1 servers, but most of these require registration/consent and are overkill for most uses and can lead to less accurate time if there is a higher delay than a Stratum 2 server.

You may also consider joining the NTP pool if you have a little bandwidth spare: http://www.pool.ntp.org/en/join.html

Comment: This answer is terrible, For starters the reasons to not use the europe servers make no sense . There is noting wrong with running a public time server without a local refclock and simply syncing to other pool servers. It is also worth noting that there is essentially no difference between the "europe" servers and the "ubuntu" servers. They both pull from the same set of pool servers. The ubuntu dns name is simply used to measure vendor usage of pool servers in default configs.

Comment: `There is noting wrong with running a public time server without a local refclock and simply syncing to other pool servers.` -- @dfc

There is something fundamentally wrong with doing this. You have added a stratum 3 server to the pool that has a massively varying error depending on the time server `ntpd` chooses. Your contribution to the pool is negligible if not negative overall. Hardcoding a known set of good servers is key. [SEE HERE](http://www.pool.ntp.org/join/configuration.html)

Comment: There is a difference between "nothing wrong"and "optimal setup." Personally the pool servers I admin all have local refclocks. I doubt you do because you assume pool clients must be stratum=3.   Massively varying error? Thanks for the LOLz.  I did'nt realize we were using a version of ntpd that does'nt groom the time sources. ntpd will smooth out the variance. Furthermore if you do add it to the pool list the pool daemon removes clocks with too much error. Adding capacity to the pool infrastructure is not negative. Run a server with  `tos minsane 7 minclock 5` and tell me about your error

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like to do deeper in the details, you can just pick the nearest server from the pool.ntp.org and end worrying about that.

Most likely the closest server to your location will get you the best time data.